# AdLds / Adam stuck every 50s

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, adam, adlds

I have a weird behaviour on my instances of AdLds / Adam.

Every 50 seconds or so, the queries takes longer to execute (2.36 seconds instead of 0.1s)
I wrote a simple test program to query my local instance with the same simple query and I get the following screenshot.

I have the same results regardless of the computer I query from or to.

Any idea of the why ?

My query code :

```
private const string Cx = "LDAP://server:389/CN=Por,DC=XXX,DC=int";
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(Cx) { Username = "username", Password = "password" };

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de)
{
      Filter = "(cn=randomUsername)",
      SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel
};
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Same problem if I use UserPrincipal. It would seem to be configuration related...

**EDIT**

I've enabled all diagnostics to full verbose on the ADAM instance but no error pops up. No message from garbage collection occurring at the time of the 2s call.

I've added the following to the registry but no changes either :

- GC Force Rediscovery Window (sec)
- GC Force Wait Expired (sec)
- GC Honor Failure Window (sec)

**EDIT**

I've seen the hotfix [ADAM service runs slowly or stops responding during garbage collection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973284/en-us#) but it only applies to W2003 and not W2008R2 / W7

Comment: how big is it? how old? is the disk fragmented? have you used the MS compact utility on it?

Comment: It's brand new installs with very little data. No ms compact.

Comment: yeah - no need to compact or defrag. have you tried the same with localhost so you can factor our some network thing that happens every 50 seconds?

Comment: I've tried A queries B, C queries B, A queries D and even on local instances. Same results.

Comment: @Vincent That's very likely the garbage collector kicking in. "Disk fragmentation" has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Is there a way to configure it ? it's a real drawback in performance when I used it from my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the other on another post : 
[AD LDS slow on first access - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790362/ad-lds-slow-on-first-access-why)

You must specify the full name of the server hosting the AdLds instance.
I don't know why at all, it's weird but it works.